# nginx routes redirect to index.html in SPA but second sub dimension

Tags: nginx, webpack, vue.js, quasar-framework

I've an vue.js (Quasar framework with webpack) app and I use vue-router. I use nginx (with laravel forge) on the server side. In the local (quasar dev or npm run dev), everything is alright. I hadn't been able to refresh pages for the address which is like /settings and I solve it with add

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
}
```

lines to nginx configuration file. After that I could refresh the /settings page on the server. But now, I can't refresh a page if it has one more dimension.

```
/survey/1
```

I tried to add these lines to nginx configuration file

```
location /survey/ {
    alias /;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

When I look at the errors, I see js addresses are wrong.

```
http://example.com/survey/js/manifest.js'
```

It should be

```
http://example.com/js/manifest.js'
```

I researched a bit but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Hi Volkan I'm dealing with this problem and you're using the same stack.. can you help me comparing with your nginx config, or how are you using laravel ?

Comment: Sure @WalterCejas I use laravel as a backend, RESTful part. If you have the same issue, I found the solution in webpack part. I'll update the answer now, it can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It's in webpack build configuration, quasar framework. I just need to modify the Project/config/index.js file's build part. Under the `build` section, `publicPath` should be updated from

```
publicPath: ""
```

to

```
publicPath: "/"
```

And it's the same for the `dev` section too. When update `dev` section's `publicPath` the problem has been fixed.

I just needed to put `"/"` to `publicPath`.